# How to expose TypeORM Repository to other modules in NestJS

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I moved all database related operations into a standalone module:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
      PostRepository,
      UserRepository,
      CommentRepository,
    ]),
  ],
  exports: [PostRepository, UserRepository, CommentRepository],
  providers: [PostsDataInitializer],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

But in other modules, when I imported the `DatabaseModule` and tried to inject `PostRepository` in service class, I got the following error.

```sh
Nest cannot export a provider/module that is not a part of the currently processed module (DatabaseModule). 
Please verify whether the exported PostRepository is available in this particular context.
```

Comment: How did you import Repositories directly? For example, from where did you import `PostRepository`? AFAIK `TypeOrmModule.forFeature` method takes an array of entity classes as the first param, not an array of repositories.

Comment: @ErangaHeshan Resolved it myself, see below.

Comment: Wow... I didn't know that you can import repositories directly. 

Comment: @ErangaHeshan Of course, it can take an array of *custom* Repository classes, see [Nestjs docs database#custom-repository](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#custom-repository).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Resolved it myself after reading [some of my Angular codes](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/client/src/app/shared/shared.module.ts), just need to export the `TypeOrmModule` in the `DatabaseModule`.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
      PostRepository,
      UserRepository,
      CommentRepository,
    ]),
  ],
  exports: [TypeOrmModule],
  providers: [PostsDataInitializer],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```